# Oracle binaries query

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

im not sure if this would be considered as a question or not. I would delete it if not counted for. But just wanted to know, where can I get Oracle 12.1.0.1 software binaries.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-linux-download-2240591.html

gives me 12.1.0.2 but what about 12.1.0.1 software?

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.1.0.1 is still available for download on edelivery.

Go to https://edelivery.oracle.com/, sign in.

Choose the `Oracle Database Enterprise Edition` product (or SE), choose your platform.

By default it will offer 12.1.0.2 for download, but you can use `Select Alternate Release`, there you can choose 12.1.0.1.

Comment: Good spot. I didn't notice `Select Alternate Release` when I logged on to check

Answer (score 3):

The software isn't on edelivery.oracle.com either, as Oracle removed 12.1.0.1 as soon as 12.1.0.2 was released. Almost as if 12.1.0.1 was a stop-gap release.

You'll have to open a support ticket with Oracle, asking for it.

12.1.0.2 was a significant bugfix release, as well as adding lots of new features (JSON storage, rapid home provisioning) - upgrade to it ASAP if you've already got 12c in production.

Comment: Ok but I hav 12.1.0.1 in prod already. So opening a ticket is the only option?

Comment: Yeah. Or you can tar up the existing `$ORACLE_HOME` and copy it over, then re-link binaries on the new host

Comment: But my existing oracle home is a RAC database and im copying it to another server were I would setup a standalone database. Won't there be any issues in re-linking the binaries?

Comment: I've not had problems doing it with 11.2... Best bet is to open a support ticket, especially if you're putting it in production on the new box

Comment: There's an "official" procedure for cloning an Oracle home (Doc ID 1493677.1 for 12.1.x) using OUI, if you're interested @tesla747. (There is/used to be a clone.pl script too somewhere that didn't require OUI IIRC, but I'm not seing docs for that in 12c.)

Comment: Be aware that if you move an Oracle home from one server to another, the new server must use the same path to the Oracle home, since the binaries hard code the path to the Oracle home in many files. You should also make sure that they are running the same OS with the same patches, otherwise you might need to relink the binaries.